# Spotify metadata API returning albums with territory nodes not populated. Does this mean that the album is globally available?

Tags: spotify

There is no reference I can find on the developer.spotify.com that mention the possibility of an empty territories node.

Below is extracted from https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/

> Blockquote
>   Territory restrictions
>   Albums and tracks in Spotify are subject to territorial restrictions. The APIs expose in which country each album and track may be played. In the album element (of album and track search), there is an element called availability. Inside it, there is an element territories. It contains a list of the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes in which the album is available. The value may also be the special string “worldwide”, indicating that the album can be played anywhere.

Example API call that contains the empty territories node in the albums:
[http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:3szB1rM9ryxhx1zasR0vVj&extras=album](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify%3aartist:3szB1rM9ryxhx1zasR0vVj&extras=album)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that album is not available anywhere. It looks like that artist may need to be merged with spotify:artist:4AK6F7OLvEQ5QYCBNiQWHq. I have just reported that to the content team.

If you try [http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:4AK6F7OLvEQ5QYCBNiQWHq&extras=album](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify%3aartist:4AK6F7OLvEQ5QYCBNiQWHq&extras=album) it should work just fine.